# Contributor License Agreements and anonymous/pseudonymous contributors

Tags: contributor, contributor-agreements

If a user contributes under pseudonym or even anonymously, how does this affect CLAs? Does it help anything if he signs a CLA with that pseudonym?

Comment: Do all your contributions require a digital signature?

Comment: a CLA is in most cases a "wet" agreement requiring an explicit consent of a person or org. How could such an agreement by anonymous?

Comment: Do you have  a specific example and pointer to the CLA in question?

Comment: @MadHatter not really. One of the options I was thinking about is asking contributors to sign contributions digitally and attach the CLA with the contribution. Even without it name we would have both things tied together, but I was hoping someone had a better idea.

Comment: @PhilippeOmbredanne I guess I didn't express myself correctly. I'm working on the implementation of a CLA in the project, but my problem is that some contributors work under a pseudonym and won't want to give their name. We also receive some anonymous contributions. I'm asking about how to tackle these cases.

Comment: My advice is to avoid CLAs. They are a barrier to contribution.
They are simpler ways: The Linux DCO does not require a signature and is  neat and well tested at scale: http://developercertificate.org/
Or licenses such as Apache 2.0 include a CLA.
CLA and custom CLA  s**ck IMHO

Comment: Requiring all contributions to be signed deals fairly well with pseudonymous contributors: you can prove the digitally-signed CLA came from the same person who contributed the content that CLA covers.  Anonymous contributions are harder to deal with, and a project that requires a strong CLA will likely not allow them.

Comment: See also these articles on why CLA s**ck: http://ebb.org/bkuhn/blog/2014/06/09/do-not-need-cla.html or why they may ok at times: https://julien.ponge.org/blog/in-defense-of-contributor-license-agreements/ (and the mention of Apache as a license with a CLA baked in)

Answer (score 2):

For books: publishing as anonymous is permitted, but the editor needs to know the author real name, or when needed, the author is required to proof his authorship.

I interpret that a CLA is some kind of agreements to the "editor", so I think you should disclose your real name.

Note: a truly anonymous contributor cannot enforce his own rights (of copyright), so as alternative, you can publish the work in public domain, which usually avoids CLA requirements.