# Does a CLA have to contain the complete name and mailing address of the person that signs it? Isn't having the contributor's GitHub username enough?

Tags: github, contributor-agreements

https://www.clahub.com/pages/why_cla ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170518031139/https://www.clahub.com/pages/why_cla)) claims that:

> A CLA should also contain personal information about the person that signs it, such as a complete name and mailing address.

Is it true that a CLA (Contributor License Agreement) have to contain  the complete name and mailing address of the person that signs it? Isn't having the contributor's GitHub username enough?

I am asking as I use the GitHub CLA management bot https://cla-assistant.io ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170518031224/https://cla-assistant.io/)) for my projects, and it only records the contributor's GitHub username:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Contributor License Agreements and anonymous/pseudonymous contributors](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/2847/contributor-license-agreements-and-anonymous-pseudonymous-contributors)